# ¿Como manipular y modificar el tiempo de cierre de sesión automático de laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Cuando dejo de utilizar mi aplicación, hecha en laravel 5.3, y vuelvo al cabo de 1h o mas refresco el navegador y me ha deslogueado el usuario.

¿Puedo modificar esa parte de laravel?, quisiera que me redirigiera puesto que tengo que refrescar la pagina para que me envié al login.

He buscado en Internet y no consigo nada acerca de ese tema o no se buscar de ese tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal Pablo,

Revisa en [nombre app]/config/session.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder amigo. Ese tiempo es en minutos, ¿cierto? ¿Como podria hacer para que desde javascript me detecte si esta logueado?